# Save all Settings in one step

Tags: vba, ms-word

is it somehow possible to save all my settings in just one command?

I have to save many diffrent TextBox textes and currently i have to save them all separately like this:

```
Call SaveSetting("Vertrag1", "setting", "Deckblatt", VertragsNrBox.Text)
Call SaveSetting("Vertrag1.1", "setting", "Deckblatt", DatumBox.Text)
Call SaveSetting("Vertrag1.2", "setting", "Deckblatt", ThemaBox.Text)
Call SaveSetting("Präambel1", "setting", "Präambel", TextBox1.Text)
Call SaveSetting("Vertrag2.2", "setting", "Präambel", TextBox2.Text)
Call SaveSetting("Vertrag2.3", "setting", "Präambel", TextBox3.Text)
Call SaveSetting("Vertrag2.4", "setting", "Präambel", TextBox4.Text)
```

....

Now is it possible to save them all in just one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Dim c As Control

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
        SaveSetting "Vertrag", "Settings", c.Name, c.Text
    End If
Next
```

You can also make use of the Tag property of your textbox to add some extra info